# Using InvokeRepeating if trigger is entered?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to use a bool to check for trigger before using InvokeRepeating but nothing happened. I can't put anything in the Update() method because then there'll be dozens of projectiles firing constantly.

Currently, the projectile fires every 3 seconds which is fine. However I only want those projectiles to fire if I'm standing in a trigger area (which I already have), but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
public class FireProjectile : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Player;

    public Transform launchPoint;
    public GameObject projectile;
    public float launchVelocity = 10f;
    public bool isFiring;

    void Start()
    {
            InvokeRepeating("fireProjectile", 0f, 3f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //
    }

    void fireProjectile()
    {
        var _projectile = Instantiate(projectile, launchPoint.position, launchPoint.rotation);
        _projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = launchPoint.forward * launchVelocity;
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == Player)
        {
            isFiring = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == Player)
        {
            isFiring = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning `isFiring` then do nothing with it.

Comment: I previously assigned it, but no matter how I tried to use it, either no projectiles would fire, or 100+ projectiles would fire at the same time, so I had to take it out

Comment: That `fireProjectile` clearly must use it. Add `Debug` methods into each of your methods then watch the console, you should be able to get it working, spotting where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

To mimic your code, we can set up a timer that keeps counting up to your required delay, then resets. When it resets, you can fire the projectile if you were in the trigger.

Note this is just one of many ways to accomplish this. It’s also a very simple way to stop a player spamming projectiles by moving in and out of the trigger area - the player only fires every `delay` seconds, if they’re currently within the trigger area.

```
public class FireProjectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;

    public Transform launchPoint;
    public GameObject projectile;
    public float launchVelocity = 10f;
    public bool isFiring;
    public float delay = 3;

    private float _timer;

    void Update()
    {
        _timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if ( _timer >= delay )
        {
            // reset timer and fire if with trigger area.
            _timer -= delay;
            if ( isFiring )
                fireProjectile();
        }
    }

    void fireProjectile()
    {
        var _projectile = Instantiate(projectile, launchPoint.position, launchPoint.rotation);
        _projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = launchPoint.forward * launchVelocity;
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == Player)
            isFiring = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == Player)
            isFiring = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends a lot on the desired behavior.. currently the timer runs regardless of whether you collide or not .. I would use a coroutine instead which only runs while you actually collide